# Deploying a Rails App to GCE with Passenger, but only seeing the app's file directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, passenger

I am using the Google Cloud Engine ruby stack, which uses RVM and Passenger on Debian 7. After following the Passenger configuration manual, I am only seeing a directory of the app's files when I navigate to the server root.

Here's the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName http://130.211.149.208
       DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp
       <Directory /var/www/myapp>
          Allow from all
          Options -MultiViews
          # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
          #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem was `/var/www/myapp` should be `/var/www/myapp/public`